# Add items to a multiline ListView dinamically from an other activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am doing an application with a friend and we are kind of stuck. I have alredy manage to have a multiple line LisView and ive done a custom adapter for it. What this application does is register a car from an other activity and when the Submit button is clicked we want to add 3 items from the car to the ListView we have in a Tabbed Activity. I've tried several things with Intent and Bundle to get the information and then put it in, but it gives a null error.

This is my Project untill now:

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CarType.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            MainActivity.this));

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if(tab.getPosition()==0) {

                PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, pageFragment ).commit();
            }
            if(tab.getPosition()==1){
                SecondPageFragment secondPageFragment = new SecondPageFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,secondPageFragment).commit();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

**Page Fragment:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class PageFragment extends ListFragment {

String[] cars ;
String[] modelo ;
String[] placas ;


public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


public PageFragment() {


}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle intent = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();



        cars = new String[]{intent.getString("marca")};
        modelo = new String[]{intent.getString("modelo")};
        placas = new String[]{intent.getString("placas")};



    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page_fragment, container, false);
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), cars, modelo, placas);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String [] cars ;
String [] modelo ;
String [] placas ;
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;


public Adapter(Context context, String[] cars, String[] modelo, String[] placas){
    super(context, R.layout.single_row, cars);

    this.c=context;
    this.cars=cars;
    this.modelo=modelo;
    this.placas=placas;



}

public class ViewHolder{
    TextView cars;
    TextView model;
    TextView placas;


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,null);

    }

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.cars=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.model=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    holder.placas=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    holder.cars.setText(cars[position]);

    holder.model.setText(modelo[position]);
    holder.placas.setText(placas[position]);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

**CarType:** this is the form of which I want to get the information to the List View

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;

public class CarType extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton androidImageButton;
ImageView imageView;
static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_type);

    final EditText etMarca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMarca);
    final EditText etModelo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etModelo);
    final EditText etPlacas = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPlacas);
    final EditText etColor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etColor);
    final CheckBox cbCamioneta = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbCamioneta);
    final CheckBox cbCar = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbCar);
    final boolean checkStatus = cbCamioneta.isChecked();



    Button bSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);


    assert bSubmit != null;
    bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Adapter.class);
            intent.putExtra("marca", etMarca.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("modelo", etModelo.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("placas", etPlacas.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("color", etColor.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("camioneta", cbCamioneta.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("car", cbCar.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("checkboxstatus", checkStatus);

            startActivity(intent);


            final String modelo = etModelo.getText().toString();
            final String marca = etMarca.getText().toString();
            final String placas = etPlacas.getText().toString();
            final String color = etColor.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CarType.this, MainActivity.class);
                            CarType.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CarType.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            CarRegisterRequest carregisterRequest = new CarRegisterRequest(marca, modelo, placas, color, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CarType.this);
            queue.add(carregisterRequest);

        }
    });

    androidImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button_android);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Final_picture);
    androidImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = getFile();
            camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}



private File getFile(){
    File folder = new File ("sdcard/camera_app");

    if (!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    File image_file = new File(folder, "cam_image.jpg");
    return image_file;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";
    imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
}

}
```

After this I have an xml file for my page fragment which only includes a ListView and I have a "single_row.xml" which is the format in which is the multiline ListView.

Any Help will be very appreciated, I am quite new to Android and to this site, so I apologize if I dont get an answer directly.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Will you provide error log also update the code with relevant line number

Comment: You can pass the object itself in a parcelable via bundle, or you can save it to a database and in the new activity read it all from the db, SugarORM is an easy DB to implement. You can also use the master-detail pattern (android studio has it by default) using fragments and this way within the same activity you can swap fragments and make it look like two different activities

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy how Activities communicate in android

You need to `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` from the `MainActivity` once you started the activity for result, you will need to wait for the result in the same Activity (`MainActivity`) and you will get the result in your `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` along with all the data in that intent.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RQ_CAR = 1;
    ....


        ....
        // Open the second activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CarType.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RQ_CAR);
        ....


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == RQ_CAR && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            // Extract data and do whatever you want
        }
    }

}
```

but where can I assign the Bundle in the intent and set that resultCode to be OK?

In your second Activity (CarType), you will need to do that manually

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.put....(); // put all your data here
intent.putExtras(extras);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Comment: Shouldn't I the first part of the code in the fragment? or MainActivity is ok?

Comment: It depends. Who will start and get the result?

Comment: The ListView is in the Fragment (PageFragment.java) so I should put the OnActivityResult on Fragment page right? I how do I add it dinamically?? im a bit lost still, sorry :/

Comment: What I want the code to do is have an empty list at first, when they lick the fab button it will take them to CarType.class and there is a from there with car model, color, license plate, etc. and once they put submit I want 3 items like car type, model ,color to add tot list view which is in the PageFragment. Thanks for your help Ahmed Hegazy